# Change Default Font for a Specific Language

Tags: fonts, language-support, default

Is there any way to change the default font for a specific language like Persian/Farsi?
I don't want to change the whole font system. I like Ubuntu Font very much but the Persian/Farsi version is very bad and it's difficult to read.
I've Unity Tweak Tool installed but it doesn't provide any option, to change the font for a specific language/font Family.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks a lot.
OS: Ubuntu 14.10

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create the file `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/90-my-farsi.conf` and give it this contents as a starter:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <match target="pattern">
        <test name="lang" compare="contains">
            <string>fa</string>
        </test>
        <test qual="any" name="family">
            <string>sans-serif</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
            <string>Homa</string>
        </edit>
    </match>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test name="lang" compare="contains">
            <string>fa</string>
        </test>
        <test qual="any" name="family">
            <string>serif</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
            <string>Homa</string>
        </edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```

That file results in the Homa font (included in the fonts-farsiweb package) being selected at first hand when Persian is the selected language.

```
$ LANG=fa_IR fc-match
homa.ttf: "Homa" "Regular"
$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, outstanding, if I want to change 'Homa' to something else, I should only replace Homa with another font, right?

Comment: @williclarkam: Right (it must be installed, of course). If the default setup is "very bad", as you said, you may want to file a bug about it. As an example, if the above file would be an improvement, it could be included by default.

Comment: I've tried your solution. And in Libreoffice it changes the writing font to the proper font that I've chosen when i change my language to persian. but i want to apply this font system-wide, to see the Persian folder names with that font. system still shows Persian names with Ubuntu's  default font. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @HOS: That's sounds like a different question, so I'd suggest that you submit a new question. When doing so you can refer to this one if appropriate.

Comment: Even after applying this, google chrome matches font  with Lohit Bengali instead of "Noto Sans Bengali". What can be done?

Comment: @Anwar: Wouldn't that motivate a separate question? If you submit a question about it, just ping me, and I'll try to help if I can.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I've put a bounty on this question for Bengali. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/479643/19288 Please check

Comment: @Anwar: Did you ask a question about making "Lohit Bengali" default?

Comment: I didn't. I put a bounty on an existing question since both of them seems similar