# Change language-specific font in Ubuntu 18.04 not working

Tags: 18.04, fonts

I recently upgraded my OS from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. I'm trying to change language-specific fonts in Ubuntu 18.04.

Placed a config file in `/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-language-selector-fa.conf` with following content and reloaded my settings.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <match target="pattern">
        <test name="lang" compare="contains">
            <string>fa</string>
        </test>
        <test qual="any" name="family">
            <string>sans-serif</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
            <string>Vazir</string>
        </edit>
    </match>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test name="lang" compare="contains">
            <string>fa</string>
        </test>
        <test qual="any" name="family">
            <string>serif</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
            <string>Vazir</string>
        </edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```

But I still get the following output:

```
╰─○ LANG=fa fc-match                                       
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
```

Or

```
╰─○ LANG=fa_IR fc-match             
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
```

Or (updated)

```
╰─± fc-match -a | head -10
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Condensed"
DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "ExtraLight"
DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Bold"
DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Condensed Bold"
DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Oblique"
DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Condensed Oblique"
DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Bold Oblique"
DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Condensed Bold Oblique"
n019003l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular
```

It seems Ubuntu 18.04 is not loading my config file. 
BTW, Vazir font installed and displayed in font manager.

Comment: What does this output: `fc-match -a | head -10`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Question updated.

Comment: Hmm.. Is the `fa_IR` locale at all generated? What does `locale -a` output?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson `fa_IR` wasn't installed. But I generated `fa_IR` locale and reloaded settings, still no change.

Comment: Maybe try a user specific config file instead: https://askubuntu.com/questions/597342/change-default-font-for-a-specific-language