# Change font for a SPECIFIC language in Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: fonts, language-support

I sometimes have to write in Syriac and the default font for this is really horrible. How do I change it? I had a look at previous questions of this type but they're really old and the folders and files they ask you to change don't seem to exist in 19.10.

EDIT: So I've managed to change settings in my /etc/fonts/conf.d/ file by using the methods I've found and if I use fc-match serif:lang=syc I get the output:

SyrCOMJerusalem.otf: "Serto Jerusalem" "Regular"

ie. I've been able to set syc (classical Syriac) to the font I want (Serto Jerusalem). But ubuntu doesn't respect this it seems for some reason. I still see Nano Syriac font.

Comment: So it turns out I should have been applying the same settings to syr, not just syc.

I made this work by making an xml titled "70-syriac.xml" saved to /etc/fonts/conf.d/ based on https://askubuntu.com/questions/597342/change-default-font-for-a-specific-language?rq=1 based on "syr" and "syc" with the fonts I needed instead of farsi, ofcourse.

Comment: Also firefox and libreoffice had their own default settings which can be changed easily.